# Correct way to chain two promises when the second promise depends on the first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, es6-promise

How do I make chain two JQuery async calls using JS Promises while avoiding the pyramid of doom?
I know that I can convert a "JQuery" promise to a real promise like this:

```
Promise.resolve($.getJSON(url, params));
```

If I just want to wait for one promise, I can do this:

```
Promise.resolve($.getJSON(url1, params1))
.then(function(result){
  // do stuff
});
```

If I want to wait for two different ajax calls to be done, I can do this:

```
Promise.all(
[
  Promise.resolve($.getJSON(url1, params1)),
  Promise.resolve($.getJSON(url2, params2))
]).then(function(results_array){
  // do stuff
});
```

However, if I want one call to come after the other one, this doesn't work:

```
Promise.resolve($.getJSON(url1, params1))
.then(function(result){
  //do stuff
  return Promise.resolve($.getJSON(url2, params2));
}).then(function(result){
  //result is a promise, not the results from the second call to getJSON()...
  //and it doesn't even wait for the second call to finish.
  //result.then() is just going to bring me further into the pyramid of doom :(
});
```

Somehow, I want to call .then() on the promise constructed in the "do stuff" function.  What's the idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: You have two extra closing parenthesis around `result`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return Promise.resolve($.getJSON(url2, params2));
```

What you did was create an already resolved promise (via `Promise.resolve`) promise whose resolved value is the result of `$.get()`, which is also a promise. This is why "it doesn't even wait for the second call to finish" and "the result is a promise".

Also, you don't need to wrap the jQuery AJAX calls as they return promises. jQuery's promises act almost (but not entirely) the same as native promises.

Do this instead:

```
$.getJSON(url1, params1).then(function(result)){
  return $.getJSON(url2, params2);
}).then(function(result)){
  //result 2
});
```

Additionally, you're using jQuery. jQuery AJAX with promises can be done like this:

```
$.getJSON(url1, params1).then(function(result){
  // do stuff
});
```

Listening to multiple promises can be done this way in jQuery:

```
$.when($.getJSON(...), $.getJSON(...)).then(function(res1, res2){
  // do stuff
});
```

Comment: isn't result2 still the promise, not the response of the second getJSON call?

Comment: @user3928094 no. I'm returning a promise which resolves with the AJAX result. What you did was return a promise that resolves with a promise.

Comment: then why does Promise.resolve($.ajax(url, params)).then() work?  In the sense that it's also a promise that resolves with a promise....

Is there any way to do what I'm doing with standard EMCA promises, dodging jquery promises completely?

Comment: @user3928094 For any follow-up questions, ask another question. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266767/575527. I believe "why returning a promise resolved with a promise not work when returned from a `then`?" and "How to dodge jQuery promises completely?" are your followups.